# Founding Mechanical force exerted by a simple electromagnet to a ferromagnetic object?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

Electromagnet made by

- just a screw, a coil around it , some current I passing by, and a very small piece of iron

Purpose:

- Trying to find an expression that describes the atractive mechanical force exerted by the electromagnet to the iron, in a x distance

My question is: ¿Is there any formula, that is "precise" describing this kind of situation?